# inoERP role wise data

Tags: php, erp

I need to multiple step sells level with login,

1) Organization sell product to stockist (State wise one dealer)

2) Stockist sell product to dealer (District level dealer) (Stockist view only own purchased product and sell that product to any dealer and generate bill with own organization)

3) Dealer sell product to end customer (Dealer can view only own purchased product and sell that product to any customer and generate bill with own organization)

how it possible?

Comment: it is possible, hire a analyst and a developer and you will have your answers but not here

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get to know how to ask a proper question and improve yours.

Comment: @madalinivascu please share your contact detail

Comment: my username is my gmail adress

Comment: @madalinivascu did you get over email?